# Are environment variables in C++ writeable?

Tags: c++, memory, environment-variables

The function `getenv(const char * key)` returns `char *`.

Does it mean that I can change some character inside of returned char array?

For example

```
char * name = getenv("PROJECT_NAME");

if(name && strlen(name) > 0) name[0] = 'P';
```

Is it good practice to do this? Should I make my own copy of array? Where are environment variables stored (what part of memory)? Are they avaible till the end of program?

Thank you for your answer.

Comment: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/setenv.3.html

Comment: [Modifying the string returned by getenv invokes undefined behavior](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/getenv)

Comment: No, it's not good practice, since it invokes undefined behaviour (as noted in the link Alan Birtles provided).    The reason `getenv()` doesn't return a `const char *` (to discourage you writing to it) is that it's specification is old, from a time when C (!) didn't even support `const`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/getenv:

> Modifying the string returned by getenv invokes undefined behavior.

So you can modify it but doing so leads to undefined behavior. So you shouldn't do it